# Flash banner not working in IE/chrome

Tags: flash, internet-explorer, google-chrome, banner

```
<object classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000" width="1000" height="309" id="FlashID" title="iMathSmart">
                       <param name="movie" value="new_banner_animation_30_days_free_trial_ver_final_08_logo_border_01.swf" />
                       <param name="quality" value="high" />
                       <param name="wmode" value="opaque" />
                       <param name="swfversion" value="11.0.0.0" />
                       <!-- This param tag prompts users with Flash Player 6.0 r65 and higher to download the latest version of Flash Player. Delete it if you don’t want users to see the prompt. -->
                       <param name="expressinstall" value="Scripts/expressInstall.swf" />
                       <!-- Next object tag is for non-IE browsers. So hide it from IE using IECC. -->
                       <!--[if !IE]>-->
                       <object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="new_banner_animation_30_days_free_trial_ver_final_08_logo_border_01.swf" width="1000" height="309">
                         <!--<![endif]-->
                         <param name="quality" value="high" />
                         <param name="wmode" value="opaque" />
                         <param name="swfversion" value="11.0.0.0" />
                         <param name="expressinstall" value="Scripts/expressInstall.swf" />
                         <!-- The browser displays the following alternative content for users with Flash Player 6.0 and older. -->
                         <div>
                           <h4>Content on this page requires a newer version of Adobe Flash Player.</h4>
                           <p><a href="http://www.adobe.com/go/getflashplayer"><img src="#" alt="Get Adobe Flash player" /></a></p>
                         </div>
                         <!--[if !IE]>-->
                       </object>
                       <!--<![endif]-->
                     </object>
```

Answer (score 5):

It seems that the latest version of chrome 27.0.1453.94 m can't display multiple flash items. When fiddling around with Firebug, I thought of the following ugly, but working solution:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
                if(window.navigator.appVersion.match(/Chrome/)) {
                        jQuery('object').each(function() {
                             jQuery(this).css('display','block');
                        });
                }

        });
</script>
```

you just need to trigger something having to do with the appearance of the object to let the rendering begin. (you could als replace the object with a clone of itself, etc...).

Answer (score 0):

Same thing without jQuery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
if (window.navigator.appVersion.match(/Chrome/)) {
    function chrome_flash_redraw() {
        var objects = document.getElementsByTagName('object');

        for (var i = 0, j = objects.length; i < j; i++) {
            objects[i].style.display = 'block';
        }
    }

    if (window.addEventListener) {
        window.addEventListener('load', chrome_flash_redraw, false);
    } else if (window.attachEvent) {
        window.attachEvent('onload', chrome_flash_redraw);
    }
}
</script>
```

Just put this code anywhere in your page.